# Choppy text animation with RaphaelJS

Tags: animation, text, svg, raphael

I'm trying to animate text with RaphaelJS, but I'm encountering a choppy animation ("judder"?).  I've looked around for other issues regarding this, but I've only been able to find jQuery-specific or non-SVG topics so far.  Please let me know if I overlooked a similar question!

Essentially, I'm attempting to visually wrap a text element in a rect element and translate them simultaneously through an animation.  I know about the 'g' element, but I don't want to use it since older versions of Internet Explorer don't support it.  Instead, I'm using separate Raphael animations for the text and the rectangle:

```
var raphRect = paper.rect(
    (paperWidth/2)-rectWidth/2
    ,paperHeight-rectHeight
    ,rectWidth
    ,rectHeight            
    ,rectHeight/2
)
...
,raphText1 = paper.text(
    paperWidth/2
    ,paperHeight-(2*fontSize)
    ,'this is jumpy text?'
)
...
raphRect.animate({y : -rectHeight}, risingTime, 'linear');
raphText1.animate({y : -2*fontSize}, risingTime, 'linear');
```

I'm assuming that the judder is caused by rounding pixels in each animation frame for the text element.  Is there any way to mitigate or prevent this judder?  (Reducing the animation time is not an option...and it doesn't even look like it helps.)

(I have an example of what I'm trying to do [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dousedfirepants/h26rZ/18/).  I've included two lines of text and a bold stroke for the rect to emphasize the judder.)

Comment: There isn't much you can do about this, browsers just dont do animation very smooth at all, you can have a look at requestAnimationFrame to see if that helps but I doubt it.

Comment: Subpixel rendering for text in particular is quite poor.  Have you tried using print rather than text?  I have found that true paths antialias *much* more satisfactorily.

Comment: Normally in pure SVG you'd set the text-rendering property to geometricPrecision. That would make it smooth in Firefox for instance. Unfortunately RaphaelJS does not seem to support setting text-rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This idea is actually borrowed from Robert Longson's information about the text-rendering property.  It's true that Raphael doesn't provide direct access to this functionality, but it does provide you with a link to the dom node -- so it is but a second step to apply this style yourself, and it does indeed produce better results in Firefox at least.

Using jquery:

```
$(raphText1.node).attr( 'text-rendering', 'geometricPrecision' );
$(raphText2.node).attr( 'text-rendering', 'geometricPrecision' );
```

Staged [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/uCxBa/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any visual change between the unmodified text and the text with a set 'text-rendering' field.  I just tried the other possible values for 'text-rendering', but I still didn't see any change.  I tried it on Chrome, Firefox 3.6, Firefox 4, Firefox 9, and Firefox 10, and my operating system (if this is relevant information) is OS X (10.6.8).  Also, according to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering), Firefox treats 'geometricPrecision' as 'optimizeLegibility'...which doesn't seem good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The documentation is incorrect, Firefox doesn't treat those two values the same for SVG text.

Comment: That's odd.  The visual change was quite striking for me in 16.0.1 -- but I will confess happily that I did not test extensively.

Comment: Afterthought: font rendering in SVG still depends on the OS's font subsystem -- this may be OS X.  Would you consider using print?  I can guarantee you that the results will be satisfactory.

Comment: I'm experimenting with print right now, and all the animated transformations I'm applying do seem really smooth.  

Would you happen to know how expensive rendering text through .print() is in comparison to rendering the same text with .text(), though?  I'm going to be running the text through a text-wrapping algorithm, which requires repeated rendering so I can gauge the bounding box's resulting dimensions.  (Also, I'm going to be doing this indefinitely with several different texts.)

Anyway, I'm convinced enough to go with .print() for now.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: (I accepted the parent answer of this conversation -- I hope that's not a problem for anyone!)

Comment: I was expecting to see a substantial performance hit using print versus text but in general I've been pleasantly surprised.  Whether the svg engine does it or the system's font subsystem does it, text rendering (except for old raster fonts!) is very similar.  You can definitely reach limits -- if you check out my home page, voidblossom.com, for instance, there's a quotation that appears at the bottom using many separated printed glyphs -- but that has more to do with number of entities than anything else.  Glyph complexity is important too -- I favor simple sans-serif fonts for that reason!

Comment: Oh, right!  I should have specified that I'm using Helvetica.  That's good to know about the similar performance.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and have tried to differentways to solve it.  I have found few hacks that works for me. But they all have the same idea: you should make text not so straight.

```
"transform" : "R 0.01"
```

For example, it rotates your text on small angle. Here is the result: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IlyaB/84hp8nmk/).
I can't garantue that it will work in your browser. In stable Chrome 36 it works good, in beta or canary worse.

You could also try no so straigth font [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IlyaB/3eab6ddx/). It works good for FF.

```
"font-family" : "Comic Sans MS"
```

Other things worse to be tried:

- inreasing font size
- using bold font
- using a text path